# How to reset parent window scrollbar when iframe resizes

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm using the following script to resize an iframe when it's content changes:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
//-->
</script>
```

And the iframe:

```
    <iframe src="frontpage.html" frameborder="0" width="1000px" height="2000px" class="iframe" name="iframe_a" scrolling="no" id="iframe_a" 

onLoad="autoResize('iframe_a');window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)">
</iframe>
```

When a user navigates the iframe from a short page to a long page, the parent window allows scrolling 
to bottom of the page. This is good. But when navigating from a long page to a short page, the scrollbars (both vertical and horizontal) remain there and allow the user to scroll down, even though 
there is no content at the bottom of the page. I would like the parent window to reset so that there
is no scrolling or no extra scrolling when the iframe has changed to a smaller size and fits in the window.

Here is the page: http://milmin.nixsyspaus.org/

Comment: Why are you calling `.parent` twice? Isn't ` window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);` enough? And try to use `.scrollTop(0)` instead...

Comment: In my browser it works correct. I tried it on Androids Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that when you set the height of the IFrame, it is affecting the height of the body tag.

If you add a wrapping element to your content then take the height of this element instead, it should represent the natural height of the content, rather than reflecting the height you have set on the IFrame.

ie

```
<body><div id='wrapper'>#content</div></body>
```

then your javascript would be

document.getElementById("iframe_a").contentWindow.document.getElementById("wrapper").scrollHeight

Comment: I tried to implement this as such: 'function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .getElementById("wrapper").scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .getElementById("wrapper").scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}'     and <div id="wrapper"> contains all of the body content. Then it would not even resize to a larger size.

Comment: Since that is hard to read, here is the example page: [link](http://milmin.nixsyspaus.org/index3.html)

Comment: You put the wrapper div in the main page. It needs to be a wrapper on the content of the IFrame.

Comment: This is an old thread, but I'm still trying to resolve this. I think you are right that I need to get var 'newheight' from the actual iframe content rather than from the body, but I couldn't get this to work using your wrapper div suggestion. Here is the page as it is: www.benjaminbennett.net    and here is the page trying to get newheight from a wrapper: www.benjaminbennett.net/index2.html  Can you spot any errors?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that the wrapper div goes in the body of the content page?